How do I balance upskilling through project development with preparing for coding interviews (e.g., LeetCode-style questions)?
I'm a software developer with 1.5 years of experience, and I'm at a crossroads in my career. On one hand, I want to continue upskilling by developing projects, building tools, and gaining hands-on experience. On the other hand, I recognize that if I want to switch jobs in the future, I'll likely need to prepare for coding interviews that heavily focus on data structures and algorithms, which isn't my strong suit.
How can I strike a balance between improving my practical skills through projects and preparing for these coding interviews?
Is it better to focus on one over the other, or should I aim to do both?
When switching jobs, do developers primarily rely on their project experience, or do they also dedicate significant time to competitive programming platforms like LeetCode?
What have others done to successfully transition while maintaining a balance?
I would appreciate any insights, advice, or strategies from those who have faced a similar dilemma.

You should be able to do both. Delegate a reasonable amount to each activity as they are both important.

YAGNI is usually thought of in terms of dev.
Just in case you don't know what I mean:
"YAGNI" stands for "You Aren't Gonna Need It". It is a principle in software development that suggests developers should only implement features that are necessary for the current requirements and not add any additional functionality that might be needed in the future.
Focus on the skills you need today and where you want to go in the future. Don't sweat how to game job interviews.
I've hired hundreds of people over the years. I've never moved up someone in the list over leetcode. The ability to deliver is what counts.
To sum it up, you prepare for the interviews by delivering products and showing that you have career goals - IMHO. Other companies might view it differently.

The problem with software development is that things change rapidly. Any skills that you are not currently using in a job quickly become out of date. The most important skill is the ability to learn new ideas, new paradigms, and totally new development environments. Every other skill will be left behind.
Thus, to prepare for interviewing, focus on showing good learning and providing value to your employer.
